# Example where $\int |f(x)| dx$ is infinite and $\int |f(x)|^2 dx$ is finite

Tags: integration

I read in a book that the condition $\int |f(x)|^2 dx <\infty$ is less restrictive than $\int |f(x)| dx <\infty$. That means whenever $\int |f(x)| dx$ is finite, $\int |f(x)|^2 dx$ is also finite, right?

My understanding is that $|f(x)|$ may have a thick tail to make the integral blow up, but $|f(x)|^2$ may decay quickly enough to have a finite integral. Can someone give me an example that $\int |f(x)| dx=\infty$ but $\int |f(x)|^2 dx <\infty$. Suppose $f(x)$ is an absolutely continous function and bounded on $(-\infty, \infty)$.

Comment: It is *not* the case that $\int |f(x)|\,dx < \infty \implies \int |f(x)|^2\,dx < \infty$. Consider $f(x) = \frac1{\sqrt x}$ on $(0,1)$.

Comment: @kahen Yes, you are right. But I am interested in those $f$ which are bounded on $\mathbb{R}$. Maybe I should state that in the problem. Thank you for the good point.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

$$f(x)=\frac1{\sqrt{1+x^2}}{}$$

Answer (score 12):

You can think of the harmonic series:

$$\sum_{n \geq 1} \frac{1}{n}=\infty$$

but

$$ \sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{1}{n^2}<\infty$$.

Therefore you can choose
$$f(x) = \sum_{n \geq 1} \frac{1}{n} \chi_{[n,n+1)}$$
where $\chi_X$ is the characteristic function of the set $X$.

Answer (score 5):

For example take $f(x)=1/\lfloor x\rfloor$. Then 
$$\int_1^\infty|f(x)|dx=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac1n=\infty$$
But
$$\int_1^\infty|f(x)|^2dx=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac1{n^2}=\frac{\pi^2}{6}<\infty$$

Comment: The OP was looking for $f$ to be absolutely continuous on $\Bbb R$.

Comment: Oh, that what happens when you start answering before finishing reading the question :(

Answer (score 4):

How about:
$$f(x) = \left\{ \begin{array}{ccc}
\frac{1}{|x|} && |x| > 1  \\
1 && |x| \leq 1   \end{array} \right.$$

Comment: What about when $|x|=1$? You'll want to fix this so you can get absolute continuity on $\Bbb R$.

Comment: @CameronBuie: In that case, it should be 1 -- which *does* make it continuous. (I'd edit to change one of the bounds to be a non-strict inequality, but I don't have the rep to propose a single-character edit.)

Comment: @CameronBuie, fixed - you guys are nit-picking today :)

Comment: Still not continuous at $x=-1$. Sorry to nitpick. :S

Comment: @nbubis: You should learn to use the `cases` environment instead of `array` for functions like that. `f(x) = \begin{cases} \frac1{|x|} & |x|>1 \\ 1 & |x| \leq 1\end{cases}`.

Comment: @kahen - thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 3):

Let $$f(x)=\begin{cases}\frac1{|x|} & |x|\geq 1\\1 & |x|<1.\end{cases}$$

Answer (score 0):

The most noticeable one I think is the sinc function $$\mathrm{sinc}(x)=\frac{\sin(\pi x)}{\pi x}$$

Comment: @kahen That's why $\int |\mathrm{sinc}(x)|dx=\infty$

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, i'm presuming you mean an integral over all space?

The first answer that comes to mind, for a continuous function is going to be annoying simple;

$$ \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} x dx = 0 $$

while

$$ \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} x^2 dx = 0 $$

So any odd function will always satisfy $\int f(x) dx < \infty$, but not necessarily $\int f^2(x) dx < \infty$. That's a whole class of functions that always fit one of the conditions but not always the other.